# Mac Underscan adjusment coding problem - AppleScript

Tags: javascript, macos, applescript

I tried to use AppleScript to adjust Display > **underscan from Off to 2nd level** of the underscan setting bar. Because my Mac Mini automatically turns off the underscan setting every time I turn on the TV, or wakes up from sleep.

I took reference to some coding online, and did make the code to open the "Settings" and "Display" tabs, but I don't know the next step. Does anyone know what other encodings should be?

My Code:

```
activate application "System Preferences"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        click button "Displays" of scroll area 1 of window "System Preferences"
        delay 0.5
        
        tell tab group 1 of window "42PFD5519/30"
            click radio button "Default for Display"
            
            -- What code should i use?
            
        end tell
    end tell
    delay 0.5
    quit application "System Preferences"
end tell
```

And Reference Photo
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have a setup such as yours to test, however, this is how I code it:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
--  # Check to see if System Preferences is 
--  # running and if yes, then close it.
--  # 
--  # This is done so the script will not fail 
--  # if it is running and a modal sheet is 
--  # showing, hence the use of 'killall' 
--  # as 'quit' fails when done so, if it is.
--  #
--  # This is also done to allow default behaviors
--  # to be predictable from a clean occurrence.

if running of application "System Preferences" then
    try
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    on error
        do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    end try
    delay 0.1
end if

--  # Make sure System Preferences is not running before
--  # opening it again. Otherwise there can be an issue
--  # when trying to reopen it while it's actually closing.

repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat

--  # Open System Preferences to the 
--  # Display tab of the Displays pane. 

tell application "System Preferences" to ¬
    reveal anchor "displaysDisplayTab" of ¬
        pane id "com.apple.preference.displays"

tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "System Preferences"
        
        --  # Wait for the UI to be available.

        set i to 0
        repeat until exists ¬
            radio button 1 of ¬
            tab group of window 1
            delay 0.1
            set i to i + 1
            if i ≥ 30 then return
        end repeat

        --  # Click the target radio button
        --  # and adjust the target slider.
        
        tell tab group 1 of window 1
            click radio button "Default for display"
            set value of slider 1 to 0.2
        end tell
        
    end tell
end tell

delay 0.2

tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

**Notes:**

Typically, the *value* of a `slider` is between `0.0` and `1.0`, so I used `0.2` so it should end up where you want it, however, adjust the *value* as necessary.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown above, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Hi, Thank for your share. I avaiable to run your code seem can open & adjust the "Underscan". but whatever the value i set to ```0.1``` to  ```1``` the "Underscan" seting alway move to **Off** or ```0```

Comment: Hi @user3439894 , me again. i tried to get that slider value. and found default value is ```7000```, and i set the value to ```8000``` seem work for me.

Comment: @Terence Mak, Set the slider to the position you what, get its value, then use it in the _code_.